# Finding if an element exists within another element Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm trying to find if the '+' sign is present after the number 65692.

I've tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(activeResource + "Current_Works_Order")).findElements(By.className("fa fa-plus multipleOpsIcon"));
```

This returns a list even when the '+' is not there.

What is the best way to search for this element?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to receive a list, and only just an element, you should use the "findElement" and not "findElements".

The way you are doing to find the child element is valid, in my opinion.

What I use to check if the element is there is:

```
public static boolean checkElement(By by) {
  try {

    if (!isPresent(by)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!isVisible(by)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;

  } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;

  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}

public static boolean isPresent(By by) {
  try {

    getElement(by).getLocation();
    return true;

  } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;

  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}

public static boolean isVisible(By by) {
  try {

    return getElement(by).isDisplayed();

  } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;

  } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
  }
}

public static WebElement getElement(By by) {
  try {

    return driver.findElement(by);

  } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;

  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.